# Restrict route to external request in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, google-api-php-client

i'm learning Symfony and i'm building an app based on the Youtube API and the Google OAuth 2.0.

I'm using Annotation routes to make a simple user interface and logging system. Here are all my routes :

- /
- /auth (redirect to Google auth server)
- /auth/response (Get the Google auth code)
- /user (users settings, stored via Doctrine ORM)
- /update (ajax call url to update users settings)
- /insert (making some Youtube API requests, will be used in a Cron task)

So my problem is that I don't want users to access certain routes because they shouldn't know those routes exist, especially for the "/insert" path.

I already set conditions for the /update path like this :

```
/**
* @Route("/update", name="update", condition="request.isXmlHttpRequest()")
*/
```

The user get a 404 error and that's perfect.

Now, how can I make something similar for my others problematic routes ? Or maybe I'm absolutely doing it wrong, please tell me !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply some restrictions policies, you need to use security config (firewalls section in your case)
Documentation here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

And 404 is the wrong answer, the 401 would be right.